# Unable to use cover switch or flip switch

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma-5

Running Kubuntu 18.04.

In System Settings -> Window Management -> Task Switcher -> Main, I can select Cover Switch or Flip Switch but to no effect.

If I choose any other method (like Large Icons, etc.), it is used as expected.

How do I get Cover and Flip switch to work?

Comment: According to the help, OpenGL is required and compositing should be active.

Comment: What is the output of `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep -E -A5 "^Compositing"`?

Comment: @DKBose It says: `Compositing
===========
Compositing is not active

`

Comment: @DKBose You were bang on target. Thanks! Went to `System Settings -> Hardware -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor` and enabled it. Things working as expected now. Please write an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Will do in a short time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in `System Settings -> Window Management -> Task Switcher -> Main`, click on the `Help` button to open the corresponding help article. In it there's this:

> Cover Switch and Flip Switch effect are more fancy effects which require OpenGL. Cover Switch displays the windows in a gallery with a large thumbnail of the currently selected window in the center of the screen while all other windows are rotated on the left and right. Flip Switch displays all windows on a 3D stack. The selected window is on top of the stack and navigating through the windows will move the stack so that the new selected window is on the top.
>   If the effect provides additional settings the configure button will be activated. By clicking this button a configuration dialog will be shown.
>   Note
>   When compositing is not active or gets suspended the normal window list will be shown. There is no loss in functionality if an effect is selected and compositing is not active.

That means that one's machine should have OpenGL and that compositing should be active.

Running `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep -E -A5 "^Compositing"` would be informative.

If the output is like:

```
Compositing
===========
Compositing is active
Compositing Type: OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
OpenGL platform interface: GLX
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

both Flip Switch and Cover Switch should work.

Comment: In my case (Kubuntu 18.04) this was not true. With active compositing and type OpenGL, flip and cover switching was not working. Because desktop cube effect wasn't working either, I reinstalled the correct NVIDIA driver, for my platform, to find out that linux-modules-$(uname -r) was not installed for the kernel I was using (which also needed linux-headers-$(uname -r) to install correctly). Once I installed them and rebooted, flip and cover task switching and desktop cube worked.